# Print info about exception in python 2.5?

Tags: python, exception, printing

Python 2.5 won't let me use this syntax:

```
try:
    code_that_raises_exception()
except Exception as e:
    print e
    raise
```

So how should I print information about an exception?

Thanks

EDIT: I'm writing a plugin for a program that includes kind of a pseudo python interpreter. It prints `print` statements but doesn't show exceptions at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the 'as' keyword is a python 3 (introduced in 2.6) addition, you need to use a comma:

```
try:
    code_that_raises_exception()
except Exception, e:
    print e
    raise
```

Comment: @Mike Axiak, what if you want to catch different exceptions which I'd usually do like `ValueError as Verr, NameError as Nerr,...`?

Comment: except (ExceptionA, ExceptionB), e ?

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
  codethatraises()
except Exception, e:
  print e
  raise
```

not as easy to read as the latest and greatest syntax, but identical semantics.